# Subtracting multiple dates

Tags: entities, datetime

I have a field that is configured to have **multiple/unlimited** dates with end date.(field_date)
I want to calculate the difference of all the dates using a loop.

This is the code used for calculating `single difference`. How to use this in a multiple scenario?

```
$start_value = $entity->field_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
$end_value = $entity->field_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value2'];
$timezone = $entity->field_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['timezone'];

$start_date = new DateObject($start_value, $timezone); $end_date = new DateObject($end_value, $timezone);
$duration = $start_date->difference($end_date, 'hours');
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $duration;
```

Comment: I voted your question to be off topic because it is just a set of PHP calculations and processing on set of values.